# how to pass parameter to ajax urls (DJANGO)

Tags: python, html, django, ajax

i want to pass parameter to url path , so it will know what user that i want to change the role , but it always return error

> NoReverseMatch at /manageuser/
>   Reverse for 'editrole' with keyword arguments '{'user_name': ''}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['editroleadmin/(?P[^/]+)$']

The flow of my edit user process : there will be list of user , division and its role in table , everytime i change the role in the select option element, it automatically change if the value in the select option changed , i use change not click in the ajax .. it always error because the views didnt know which user that i want to change the value ,thats why always error , im searching that i must pass the parameter, so i do as the following but it didnt work

here's the html

```
<div class="row mt">
          <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="content-panel align-content-center">
              <table class="table table-striped table-advance table-hover">
                <thead>
                  <tr>
                    <th><i class="fa fa-bullhorn"></i> User</th>
                    <th><i class="fa fa-bookmark"></i> Email</th>
                    <th><i class="fa fa-bookmark"></i> Division</th>
                    <th><i class="fa fa-bookmark"></i> Role</th>
                    <!-- <th><i class=" fa fa-edit"></i> Status</th> -->
                    <th></th>
                  </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>  
                  {% for user in users %}
                    <tr>
                      <td class="user_name">

                        {{user.name}}

                      </td>
                      <td>
                        {{user.email}}
                      </td>
                      <td>
                        {{user.division}}
                      </td>
                      <td>
                      <select id="userroles" class="roleselect">

                        <option selected="selected">
                          {{user.role}}
                        </option>
                        {% if user.role == "Business Analyst" %}
                           <option>Admin</option>
                           <option>Manager</option>
                           <option>Segment Manager</option>
                        {% elif user.role == "Admin" %}
                           <option>Business Analyst</option>
                           <option>Manager</option>
                           <option>Segment Manager</option>
                        {% elif user.role == "Manager" %}
                           <option>Admin</option>
                           <option>Business Analyst</option>
                           <option>Segment Manager</option>
                        {% else %}
                           <option>Admin</option>
                           <option>Manager</option>
                           <option>Business Analyst</option>                       
                        {% endif %}
                      </select>
                      </div>
                      </td>                    
                    <td>

                      <button class="btn btn-danger btn-xs"><i class="fa fa-trash-o "></i></button>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                  {% endfor %}   

                </tbody>
              </table>
```

here's the script that i use . it always error in the var urls that i put in ajax

```
<script>
      $(document).ready(function() {
      $(".roleselect").change(function () {
        var urls = "{% url 'polls:editrole' user_name=user.name %}";  
        var editrole = $(this).val();

        $.ajax({                     
          url: urls,                    
          data: {
            'editrole': editrole 
          },
          success: function(data) {   
              alert("success update role");  
          },
          error: function(data)
          {
            alert("error occured");
          }
        });
      });
      });
  </script>
```

here's the views to load list user , and to edit

```
def manageuser(request):
    if request.session.get('username'):
        if request.session.get('role')== "Admin":
            import cx_Oracle           
            dsn_tns = cx_Oracle.makedsn('', '', sid='dicb') 
            conn = cx_Oracle.connect(user=r'', password='', dsn=dsn_tns) 
            c = conn.cursor() 
            c.execute("select au.id,username, email, pup.division, pup.role from auth_user au join polls_userprofileinfo pup on au.id=pup.user_id")
            c.rowfactory = makeDictFactory(c)
            databaseusertable = []
            for rowDict in c:
                databaseusertable.append({
                    'name': rowDict['USERNAME'],
                    'email': rowDict['EMAIL'],
                    'division': rowDict['DIVISION'],
                    'role':rowDict['ROLE']
                })

            context = {
                'users' : databaseusertable,
            }

            return render(request, 'manage_user.html',context)
        else :
            messages.error(request, "Must be admin to access the page")
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
    else :
        messages.error(request, "Login required")
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/')

def editrole(request,user_name):
    import cx_Oracle
    role_name = request.GET.get('editrole',1)
    print(user_name)
    print(role_name)
    guess = User.objects.get(username=user_name)
    identity = guess.id     
    print(identity)
    dsn_tns = cx_Oracle.makedsn('', '', sid='dicb') 
    conn = cx_Oracle.connect(user=r'', password='', dsn=dsn_tns) 
    c = conn.cursor() 
    c.execute("update from polls_userprofileinfo set role = '"+role_name+"' where user_id = "+guess.id)
    return redirect('/manageuser/')
```

here's the urls path

```
 path('editroleadmin/<str:user_name>',views.editrole,name='editrole'),
```

it seems i did it wrong , but i dont know where i was wrong about this , can someone help me?

Comment: you can just use `editroleadmin/{{request.user.username}}` instead since you calling from the same domain

Comment: @LinhNguyen does that mean i will pass the user.username of Admin? who have charge in editing user roles

Comment: are you trying to get username of the current logged in user ? cause that is how you do it

Comment: @LinhNguyen nope , i trying to get the username i want to change his / her role , for example , in my table i have list user of username A,B,C i want to change the role of B from manager to segment manager, i want the application know that i want to change the role of username B

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in html `tags` you can create custom data to use in Ajax:

```
<select id="userroles" class="roleselect" data-username="{{ user.name }}">
```

And in your ajax:

```
var urls = "/editroleadmin/"+ $(this).data('username');
```

Comment: woah it sends the parameter that i want in views thankyou, but i will edit a little